# How should i go about printing this? (Blackjack)

Tags: python, printing, blackjack

```
import random

cards_names = {1: "Ace", 2: "2", 3: "3", 4: "4", 5: "5", 6: "6", 7: "7", 8: "8", 
              9: "9", 10: "10", 11: "Jack", 12: "Queen", 13: "King"}

def dealing():
    return random.randint(1, 13)

def value_of_hand(cards):
    value = 0
    for card in cards:
        if 1 < card <= 10:
            value += card
        elif card > 10:
            value += 10

    if 1 in cards and value + 11 <= 21:
            return value + 11
    elif 1 in cards:
            return value + 1
    else:
            return value

def your_hand(name , cards):
    faces = [cards_names[card] for card in cards]
    value = value_of_hand(cards)

    if value == 21:
        print ("Wow, you got Blackjack!")
    else:
        print ("")

    print ("%s's hand: %s, %s : %s %s") % (name, faces[0], faces[1], value)

for name in ("Dealer", "Player"):
    cards = (dealing(), dealing())
    your_hand(name, cards)
```

Comment: I gave you an answer you most likely wanted to get, but for future reference I suggest you to read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In short: be precise about the errors you get, the part of the code you have a problem with, and the desired behavior of the code. Welcome to Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming here that you are using Python 3.x and getting this error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'tuple'

You need to move the part after % inside the prints parentheses to avoid the error. Also, you have one `%s` too much in your print. Remove that and then it prints fine:

```
print ("%s's hand: %s, %s : %s" % (name, faces[0], faces[1], value))
```

> Dealer's hand: Ace, 8 : 19
>
> Player's hand: 9, 7 : 16

As you can see, the number of `%s`:s should be equal to the parameters you provide to it. Without removing the extra %s it would print the following error on Python 3:

> TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

Also, in Python 3 you can use the new string formatting syntax:

```
print ("{}'s hand: {}, {} : {}".format(name, faces[0], faces[1], value))
```

It is sometimes more flexible than the old way of *string interpolation* with %s, and certainly useful feature to know.